# Prestashop 1.7 set-template with header and footer

Tags: php, oop, prestashop, smarty

I am using prestashop 1.7 and have created a front-controller for my module. When I am using setTemplate, it does not include the header and footer just a blank page. I have assigned a page (in backoffice) to the module controller, and in the module, I am using following code:

**/modules/somemodules/controllers/front/moduleslist.php:**

```
class somemodulesmoduleslistModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

  public function initContent(){

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
      'id' => 1,
    ));

    $this->setTemplate('module:somemodules/views/templates/front/find-modules.tpl');
  }

}
```

What I have tried in the template file:

**/modules/somemodules/views/templates/front/find-modules.tpl:**

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}
{block name='page_content'}
  {{$id}}
{/block}
```

But now errors is like, undifined language, undifined page etc.
Is there a better way of doing this, rather than re-defining all of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to call the parent method so that all standard variables get initialized.

```
public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
      'id' => 1,
    ));

    $this->setTemplate('module:somemodules/views/templates/front/find-modules.tpl');
}
```